# Does the order of any element in a ring divide the order of 1?

Tags: ring-theory

I know that if a ring $R$ is a domain, then the additive order of any element must equal the additive order of $1$. If $R$ has zero divisors, then I can think of rings with elements whose additive order divides the order of $1$ but is not equal to the order of $1$. Are there non-domain rings where not even this is true?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $1 = (1,1)$ has infinite order, but $(0,1)$ has order $2$. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I would argue that $2$ divides infinity haha. I was sort of looking for an example where both orders were finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ n\cdot 1=0$, then $ n\cdot r=0$ is a consequence by multiplying both sides with $r$.

Thus for all rings with identity, if the identity has finite additive order all elements have finite additive order, and their orders are bounded by that of 1. By elementary group theory, their orders must divide that of 1.

Comment: Why must they divide the order of $1$, if $1$ does not generate the whole ring by addition?

Comment: @Nishant It has nothing to do with generating the whole ring. You are just looking at the cyclic subgroup generated by $r$.

Comment: Right, but why does that have to be a subgroup of the cyclic subgroup generated by $1$. And if it doesn't, how can you use Lagrange?

Comment: @Nishant It looks like you are entirely distracted by $1$ :) The subgroup generated by $1$ has nothing to do with it. Even Lagrange is overkill. It's more basic than that. In any group with identity $e$, $g^n=e$ implies that the order of $g$ divides $n$. In additive notation it's just $n\cdot g=0$ implies the order of $g$ divides $n$.

Comment: @Nishant In case you've forgotten the idea: let the order of $g$ be $m>1$. Then $n=qm+r$ for some integers $q,r$, and $0\leq r<m$. Since $e=g^n=g^r$ and $r<m$, it is impossible for $r$ to be strictly greater than $0$. Thus $r=0$ and $n=qm$.

Comment: Yeah, dearp. I realized that a few hours later...thanks everyone!